# Getting white space on the right side on mobile device. Some part of table and text getting outside the mobile width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm getting strange white space on the right side of the mobile devices. I tried wrapping the page inside the body the following:

```
<div style="overflow-x:hidden"></div>
```

It removed the white space on the right side, but it also cut the contents which were overflowed before. So, I removed it. I tried in many way, but no luck so far. I used viewport meta tag and used bootstrap 3 for RWD. Can anybody help what could be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Here is the link: [http://107.180.106.101:8081/rates-go.html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stylesheet @ http://107.180.106.101:8081/Content/css/style.css, on line 460 you have

```
#page-content{
    width: 572px;
   ...
}
```

That hard coded width will cause problems at narrow viewports. One option would be to change this to something like

```
#page-content{
     width: 572px;
     max-width: 100%
     ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

**Update**
One option to tweak your mobile menu would be to add something like the following to your CSS:

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-static-top {
        margin-right: 0; 
    }  
}
```

Comment: can you please see what happens to this page in the nav button in mobile view? The nav in mobile view is not showing full width? I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance. http://107.180.106.101:8081/home2.html